# rails 3.1.3: trying to run locally in production, asset pipeline not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

My app runs fine in development mode.

When I run in production mode using `RAILS_ENV=production rails s` none of my .css or .js files get loaded. (I did precompile assets, using `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`.)

The webrick log shows:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-a73ce43be7bf75953cd0c60b2b4a7eb0.js"):

and

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-986dd79830088c416c1632c12999ec69.css"):

The files were compiled (according to the log\production.log file) and my public/assets directory does show those files with and without the fingerprint:

```
ls public/assets
application-986dd79830088c416c1632c12999ec69.css
application-986dd79830088c416c1632c12999ec69.css.gz
application-a73ce43be7bf75953cd0c60b2b4a7eb0.js
application-a73ce43be7bf75953cd0c60b2b4a7eb0.js.gz
application.css
application.css.gz
application.js
application.js.gz
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Rails doesn't serve static assets in production mode by default. If you want to disable this and serve the static assets, update your `config/environments/production.rb` file with this:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

The reasoning behind Rails' default configuration is that it assumes you'll be running behind a standard web server in production mode (Apache, Nginx, etc.) which will then proxy the requests to your Rails app. Since the assets are precompiled, Apache/Nginx/etc. can directly serve them without needing to talk to your Rails processes.

Comment: @Dylan Just ran into the same problem - thanks for the awesome explanation!